# How to spawn an async function in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, spawn, dart-isolates, spawning

How an I spawn an Isolate blocking on an async function in Flutter?

I tried `dart:cli`'s `waitFor` function, but it seems that `dart:cli` does not work together with Flutter.

Comment: There is no supported way to block on an `async` function.  Why would you need an `Isolate` to block anyway?  Why can't you just `await` the `Future`?

Comment: @jamesdlin because `Isolate.spawn` spawns a non-async function and therefore I can't in it `await` the `Future`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no supported way to block on an `async` function.

You shouldn't need an `Isolate` to block anyway.  Each `Isolate` has its own event loop and can just `await` the `Future` returned by your asynchronous function before calling `Isolate.exit`.  For example:

```dart
import 'dart:isolate';

void foo(SendPort p) async {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    print('foo: $i');
  }

  Isolate.exit(p);
}

void main() async {
  var p = ReceivePort();
  await Isolate.spawn(foo, p.sendPort);
  print('Isolate spawned.');

  // Wait for the Isolate to complete.
  await p.first;
  print('Done');
}
```

which prints:

```
Isolate spawned.
foo: 0
foo: 1
foo: 2
foo: 3
foo: 4
Done
```